# Why my python function sum_points always return the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does my program always output the same result? (5).
With the function `sum_points` I am trying to sum the points to check if the player points are > 21 to check if he is still safe or he lost.

I don't know why but I am always getting 5 as output of the function `sum_points` even if it should sum the values at the index of the faces array, so the sum of the 2 picked cards values

```py
import random

card_values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
suits = ["spades", "clubs", "hearts", "diamonds"]
       # 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  J   Q   K   A
faces = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
faces_display = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]


class Card:
    def __init__(self, face, suit):
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit

def create_deck():
    cards = []
    for x in range(2):
        for suit in suits:
            for face in faces_display:
                c = Card(face, suit)
                cards.append(c)

    random.shuffle(cards)
    return cards

def display_cards(cards_list):
    for card in cards_list:
        print(card.face +"\t"+ card.suit)

def sum_points(cards):
    tot = 0
    for card in cards:
        tot += faces[cards.index(card)]

    return tot


def play_hand():
    cards = create_deck()

    dealer_cards = []
    player_cards = []

    # deal initial cards
    dealer_cards.append(cards.pop(0))
    dealer_cards.append(cards.pop(0))
    player_cards.append(cards.pop(0))
    player_cards.append(cards.pop(0))

    dealer_score = sum_points(dealer_cards)
    player_score = sum_points(player_cards)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cards = create_deck() 
    c = []
    c.append(cards.pop(0))
    c.append(cards.pop(0))

    display_cards(c)
    print(sum_points(c))
```

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to learn som common debugging techniques. For example using `print` calls to print values inside your algorithms, to see that everything is updated as you expect. Or why not learn how to use an actual *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as others have said, `tot += faces[cards.index(card)]` is only returning the index of the card list that you passed to the `sum_points` function.

With your code, I think what you wanted is something like this

```
tot += faces[faces_display.index(card.face)]
```

Better yet, I think it would be easier to have a dictionary of the containing the face display and face values like `face_dict = {"J" : 10, "Q" : 10}` and so on, so you can use

```
 tot += face_dict.get(card.face)
```

Which in my opinion is more readable.

Comment: Actually I think I love you. Not only you provide me the answer but you also propose a good solution for the problem

Comment: Actually you may also just add the values to the card object.

Answer (score 0):

You are always grabbing the cards 2 and 3. You aren't making a random selection of cards in the create_deck() function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're actually getting the cards from a list that only has those two cards.

When you call `sum_points`, `c = [cards[0], cards[1]`. Inside `sum_points`, you are requesting the index of the elements inside the **same list you received as a parameter**; therefore, the indexes will be `0` and `1`.

An example would be:

```
sum_points(cards=[1,2]):
   tot += faces[cards[indexOf(1)]] # This is faces[0]!!!
   tot += faces[cards[indexOf(2)]] # This is faces[1]!!!
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your `create_deck()` function is not random, it always generates the numbers `0, 1` in `range(2)`, and therefore picks 2 and 3, as these are indexes `0` and `1` of your lists of cards.

It does shuffle the cards afterwards, but this won't change anything when you go to add them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
        tot += faces[cards.index(card)]
```

Here you're iterating over an array and then accessing `cards.index(card)` which is the index of the card in the array, in your case since there are two cards it will always be 0 for the first and 1 for the second. Because of that you're always accessing faces[0] and faces[1] and summing them thus giving you 2 + 3 = 5.